# How to integrate surface area of the Mobius strip using 'density'?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, mobius-band

https://www.quora.com/Can-you-do-a-surface-integral-on-a-mobius-strip

According to this link, it is possible to integrate surface area of the non-orientable Mobius strip by using density. However, I'm trying to understand explanations in the Wikipedia, I don't know from which equation I should start to calculate it. Please help me.

Comment: The Mobius strip is the total space of a fiber bundle. In particular, it's locally trivial; set up a partition of unity and integrate over locally trivial patches. The problem is that there isn't a global volume form or trivial normal bundle, so you're a bit restricted in what you can sort of integration you can do that's independent of parametrization, etc.

Comment: @anomaly Can I ask how can I set up a partition of unity for the Mobius strip? Actually, I'm a highschooler who is really interested in this field and want to solve this problem but have restricted experience in mathematics.

Comment: Going into the details of the construction is a bit too much for a comment, but the idea is that if you take a small part of the Moebius strip, then it is orientable, and you can compute the surface area as usual. Divide the space up into small parts, integrate over them, and you're done. A construction of unity just deals with the bookkeeping for it; it's not as crucial as it would be in a non-compact space, where the main issue is that elements in partition of unity have compact support.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $D$ be a region in the $(u, v)$-plane, such as a rectangle. To integrate a (continuous) scalar function $f$ over a (piecewise-$C^{1}$) parametrization $\Phi:D \to \Reals^{3}$, form the *scalar surface element*
$$
dS = \|\Phi_{u} \times \Phi_{v}\|\, du\, dv,
$$
and put
$$
\int_{\Phi} f = \int_{D} f\, dS.
$$
This formula does not depend on orientation, and it gives a meaningful answer even if, say, the image of $\Phi$ is a Möbius strip obtained by identifying boundary points of $D$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Just asking, Isn't there any other way to use density from the parameterised equation of the Mobius strip? not from the rectangle  before the strip is twisted?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. In case it helps: Even when you integrate over an orientable surface, the integral is expressed over the parameter domain. If you're asking about physical interpretation, note that a Moebius strip made of aluminum foil (say) _has a well-defined mass_ (and a well-defined center of mass), even though the strip is non-orientable.

Comment: $dS$ *is* the density (what is a density, after all, but the absolute value of a—not necessarily globally well-defined—volume form?).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang The parameterised equation what I meant was this; x(u,v)= (1+ v/2cos(u/2)cosu, y(u,v)=(1+v/2cos(u/2)sinu, z(u,v)=v/2sin(u/2). Is it irrelevant after all when interpreting the Mobius strip in terms of density? Is the scalar function you meant at the first mean the original rectangle-shaped piece of paper before I twist one?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin What do you mean by the volume form of the Mobius strip?

Comment: Well, for a surface it is the *area* form, not volume form. When you have an oriented surface and $e_1,e_2$ is a positively-oriented orthonormal basis for the tangent space, the area $2$-form $\sigma$ satisfies $\sigma(e_1,e_2)=1$. When we don't have an orientation, we're going to get either $1$ or $-1$. But then $|\sigma|(e_1,e_2) = |\sigma(e_1,e_2)|=1$, regardless. The *density* $|\sigma|$ is a well-defined object on the surface.

Comment: @7_G.S.N: The scalar function $f$ could be the constant function $1$, giving the area of the Moebius strip; it could be a Cartesian coordinate $x$, $y$, or $z$, whose integral (divided by the area) would be a coordinate of the centroid; and so forth. The parametrization $\mathbf{x}$ (which I called $\Phi$), through its vector-valued partial derivatives, is used to calculate $dS$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. The region $D$, for your $\mathbf{x}$, could be taken as $[0, 2\pi] \times [-1, 1]$.